# Angular Material Customizing Typography

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a question about using Angular Material. I think it's interesting for everyone.

I’m on a project that was prototyped in figma. So the colors, fonts and components were all planned out before building the app.

**Typography**

In the prototype, all possible types of fonts that the application will have were defined.
15 font styles have been defined across the app. But of course this could change, it could be implemented more in the future.

[image]

As we know, the Angular Material library [customizing typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) has Typography levels already defined, 13 typography levels that Angular Material themes and components use.

**Doubt**

So we can see that the font styles already defined in Angular Material do not suppress the application's prototype requirements.

**Reasons**

- The styles already defined are not compatible with what the prototype requires, such as -
- font size, letter spacing, line height…
  The prototype wants more font styles as it will have 15 styles or more in the future.

**Possible solution**

Add in the theme all the fonts that the prototype requires, so that we can use them in the app's own components

**Pros**

For all the app's own components, we can use the fonts

**Cons**

For all Angular Material components that the app will use, for example Button, we must
update the natural font style to the style that was added according to the prototype.
Let's completely ignore the already defined Angular Material font styles

What would be the most appropriate strategy to follow?

We are using Angular 14

Comment: Hey Gabriel how did you solve this problem? Kinda in the same position right now, predefined styles in figma design which do not correspond with angular material 15 at all